# Windows Phone 8.1 Universal App URL Encoding for Parse.com

Tags: c#, parse-platform, windows-phone-8.1

I'm working on a Windows Phone universal app using the rest API provided by parse.com. I'm having some difficulties understanding how to apply constraints to my requests using c#.

```
curl -X GET \
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: xLASDHJJA9soTULpj0ySGTNDl0LjtXcF0senHAO" \
-H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: 86iKL3MqAKKOWS90OiFOKIdjnoPrzkn5K2Xc7" \
-G \
--data-urlencode 'where={"playerName":"Sean Plott","cheatMode":false}' \
https://api.parse.com/1/classes/GameScore

//I've tried using something like this
string url = "google.com/search?q="; + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("Example");

//I've also tried something using UriEscape but I deleted my code as it was clearly very wrong
Uri.EscapeUriString()
```

This is the example provided by parse for Curl. I have been wrestling with it for a while trying to figure out how to get this to work in C# while being suitable for an app. If anyone can provide an example of how this is done in c# it would be greatly appreciated.

https://parse.com/docs/rest#queries-basic

Comment: You shouldn't show us your actual id and key. I would recommend contacting Parse about resetting it, if that's it.

Comment: Nah that's just a bunch of random characters i added to the example in the docs

Comment: Okay :) Just wanted to make sure.

Comment: show us what you tried already!